# Page path level option in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics

I have issue about **Page path level**, My URLs is like these:

```
example.com/en/news/post-id/title
```

and I want show just **post-id** in a column
[image: like this.]
But in my data studio in dimension there is no **Page path level** option. (maybe its because of the Google Analytics4) So how can I do this?

Comment: Ive not dived into DataStudio in quite a while. You will likely want to look at calculated fields (can be used for dimensions or metrics) https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en&ref_topic=7570421#zippy=%2Cin-this-article and then using a regex extraction to return what you are after
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en&ref_topic=7041728